# Visual Studio: Code Cleanup ignoring "Add 'this' or 'Me' qualification' fixer

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 17.3, I have "Add 'this' or 'Me' qualification" in my included fixers for Profile 1.  However, when I run code cleanup, this fixer is not applied.

[image]

I have tried removing the fixer and re-adding it and restarting Visual Studio with no luck.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem just minutes ago. I reached this question for an answer, and didn't find one.

for a last resort.

At Visual Studio menu, Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code-style > General, and updated my preferences. (it was already set, when I was facing that problem).

and here is what I have done as a change

**generate .editorconfig file from settings.**

and voila, problem solved for me.